# python asynchronous httprequest

Tags: python, xmlhttprequest

I am trying to use twitter search web service in python. I want to call a web service like:

```
http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed
```

from my python program.

Can anybody tell me

1. how to use xmlhttprequst object in python
2. how to pass parameters to it, and
3. how to get the data in dictionary.

Here is my try:

```
import urllib
import sys
url = "http://search.twitter.com/search.json?q=blue%20angels&rpp=5&include_entities=true&result_type=mixed"
urlobj = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = urlobj.read()
print data
```

Thanks.

Comment: you can make async calls using http://eventlet.net/doc/

Comment: tried urllib, and stackoverflow search. Please feel free to mark as duplicate, I will be happy to know the duplicate link that can solve my problem.

Comment: @hrishikeshp19 It seems that you are searching for code that you can copy and paste, instead of trying to actually solve this thing by understanding it. This is generally frowned upon.

Comment: Edited to show what have I tried.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You don't need "asynchronous httprequest" to use twitter search api:

```
import json
import urllib
import urllib2

# make query
query = urllib.urlencode(dict(q="blue angel", rpp=5, include_entities=1,
                              result_type="mixed"))  
# make request
resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?" + query)

# make dictionary (parse json response)
d = json.load(resp)
```

There are probably several libraries that provide a nice OO interface around these http requests.

To make multiple requests concurrently you could use [`gevent`](http://www.gevent.org/):

```
import gevent
import gevent.monkey; gevent.monkey.patch_all() # patch stdlib

import json
import urllib
import urllib2

def f(querystr):
    query = urllib.urlencode(dict(q=querystr, rpp=5, include_entities=1,
                                  result_type="mixed"))
    resp = urllib2.urlopen("http://search.twitter.com/search.json?" + query)
    d = json.load(resp)
    print('number of results %d' % (len(d['results']),))

jobs = [gevent.spawn(f, q) for q in ['blue angel', 'another query']]
gevent.joinall(jobs) # wait for completion
```

Answer (score 4):

I'd recommend checking out [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/) and its [`async` module](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/user/advanced/#asynchronous-requests).

### Simple request:

```
import json
import requests

params = {'rpp': 5, 'include_entities': 1, 'result_type': 'mixed',
          'q': 'blue angel'}

r = requests.get('http://search.twitter.com/search.json', params=params)

print json.loads(r.text)
```

### Async:

```
import json
from requests import async

def add_option_params(args):
    options = {'rpp': 5, 'include_entities': 1, 'result_type': 'mixed'}
    args['params'].update(options)
    return args

requests = []

for search_term in ['test1', 'test2', 'test3']:
    request = async.get('http://search.twitter.com/search.json',
                        params={'q': search_term},
                        hooks={'args': add_option_params})
    requests.append(request)

for result in async.map(requests):
    print result.url, json.loads(result.text)['completed_in']
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the simple request approach doesn't work anymore because Twitter removed their REST API since this answer was posted: `The Twitter REST API v1 is no longer active. Please migrate to API v1.1. https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/overview.` Also, it seems `async` was removed from `requests` since; `ImportError: cannot import name async`