# Is there a way to know the AJAX request that requested a certain HTML element?

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome, web-scraping, xmlhttprequest

It's probably a shot in the dark, but I'm trying to scrape certain elements from Youtube by using BeautifulSoup and requests in Python. However, most elements are only loaded by xhr requests and obviously I can't run js in Python.

I tried reading the js source files but they're minified and really hard to understand. So is there a way I can point at an element from Chrome and somehow know which Javascript method brought it to life?

Comment: No (filler, more filler)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Chrome Developer Tools - Dynamically Created Element](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27112163/chrome-developer-tools-dynamically-created-element)

Comment: Maybe consider calling the XMLHTTPREQUEST from the python code instead of JS? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9754562/python-asynchronous-httprequest

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do. But the problem is I don't know how to find the xhr request that caused this change.

I tried setting a breakpoint as was suggested in Josh Lee's link, but this only works if the page won't render again.

Comment: Consider using selenium python library. selenium-python.readthedocs.io It is web browser (usually Firefox) driver. You can programmatically drive the browse, wait for elements and then process it or control it. While you can wait for element appearance the AJAX is not problem anymore. Personally I think that it is better than screen scaping.